Why Didn't Ghosts Escape When the Proton Fields Went Down?
I enjoyed the new Ghostbusters: Frozen Empire, but this one line still bothers me:

Lars, why haven't the ghosts escaped yet?

Later on, the proton fields are restored and all is well.  But I didn't catch any explanation why the ghosts stayed in confinement?

Probably fear of Garraka.
We previously see that the miniature Stay-Puft Marshmallow ghosts are afraid of Garraka, since they all run and hide when the orb containing him is placed on the counter, but we also know that Garraka is capable of controlling ghosts, as we see that the orb can force the marshmallow ghosts to come to it. We also see this reflected in the Possessor, which obeys Garraka as soon as the two come into contact, and Phoebe's ghost, which Garraka can use to control her body.
Since the proton fields were disabled by Garraka inside the orb, I think the clear implication is that the other ghosts were too afraid to leave with Garraka there—until, of course, Garraka started to exert his will upon them, after which they all tried to escape as vigorously as possible, such as the Possessor trying to crack the glass around its room.
